# How to change the file name before storing it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my View I am allowing users to upload resume and optionally cover letter.
However to avoid duplication I should be able to change the file name. Below is the piece of code in my controller. Please advise how I can change the file name before storing it.

```
foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
{
    if (Request.Files[upload].ContentLength == 0) continue;
    string pathToSave = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
    Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathToSave, filename));
}
```

Comment: you should look at the SaveAs method.  That will create the file you are saving on your server.  Since you are passing something to that method that combines your file path and file name, perhaps if you changed something about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var formattedFileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}{2}"
            , Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)
            , Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
            , Path.GetExtension(filename));
```

If original file name is `John.pdf` that will produce `John-b3d3d49c60e0426a8e4ff3fabff1c4e9.pdf`

That approach has some advantages:

- there will be no conflict if 2 or more files with same name are uploaded within one second
- you can sort files in directory by name

Comment: Well this is exactly what i was hoping to find. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use a DateTime value to make it unique

```
 Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(pathToSave, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_mm_ss") + "_" + filename));
```

Comment: This is what I do. @olu beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4):

When you call `SaveAs` you can save as whatever you want.

I often do something like this:

```
var filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
fullpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fullpath) + filename;
file.SaveAs(fullpath);
```

where `file` is the `HttpPostedFileBase`